# Jasmine Jquery TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jasmine

My task is to set the table header width=250px and unit test it with Jasmine. Below code runs perfectly on JSFiddle site but when I am trying to run in the project it shows the error: "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined" in the Developer Tool of Chrome browser.

Test File:

```
describe('The success button', function(){   
   var fixture;
   beforeEach(function() {
   setStyleFixtures('th.reportHeaderCell { width:250px; }');
   fixture = setFixtures('<table> <tr><th class="reportHeaderCell">Success</th></tr></table>');
  });

   it('should have width= 250px', function() {
   var successHeader = fixture.find('.reportHeaderCell');
   expect(successHeader.css('width')).toEqual('250px');
  });
});
```

I took reference from the below blog:
http://www.itsmycodeblog.com/jasmine-jquery-testing-css/

This is my first time testing with Jasmine. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your HTML is missing a closing `</table>` tag, try that?

Comment: It still shows the same error. Though thank you for the suggestion. I corrected that mistake.